# Set value to vaadin combobox(polymer)

Tags: combobox, polymer, vaadin-elements

I have a system where I can select a value in a vaadin-combobox or select the value in another div (with a svg) and set the combo's value dynamically. How can I set the combo's value?

I already tried value="", but this didn't work...

Comment: Can you show the code that you've tried? That would allow us to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** To bind the combobox's value to the first array item, you'd use a computed binding:

```
<vaadin-combo-box
  value="[[_getFirstItem(sessions)]]"
  ...>
</vaadin-combo-box>
```

where `_getFirstItem()` is a method on your Polymer object:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'x-foo',
  ...
  _getFirstItem: function(sessions) {
    return sessions.length > 0 && sessions[0];
  }
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.5.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/master/vaadin-combo-box/vaadin-combo-box.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <vaadin-combo-box
        label="Element"
        items='[[sessions]]'
        value="[[_getFirstItem(sessions)]]">
      </vaadin-combo-box>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo',
          properties : {
            sessions: {
              type: Array,
              value: function() {
                return ["Bohrium", "Boron", "Bromine", "Cadmium", "Caesium", "Calcium"];
              }
            }
          },
          _getFirstItem: function(sessions) {
            return sessions.length > 0 && sessions[0];
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/pbjEqM?editors=1000)</sup>

---

From [docs for `vaadin-combobox`](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/elements/vaadin-combo-box/vaadin-combo-box-value.html):

> You need to provide the set of items which the user can select with the `items` property. Current selection is indicated by the `value` and `selectedItem` properties. You can set or change the selection programmatically by setting the `value` property. Doing so also updates the visible fields.
>
> When setting the items declaratively, notice that the attribute value needs to be a valid JSON string. You need to use single quotes for the attribute value and double quotes inside the value (in the JSON string). Alternatively, you can escape the double quotes inside the value.
>
> ```
> <vaadin-combo-box
>   label="Element"
>   items='["Bohrium", "Boron", "Bromine", "Cadmium", "Caesium", "Calcium"]'
>   value="Bromine">
> </vaadin-combo-box>
> ```
>
> Setting the items and value programmatically:
>
> ```
> var combobox = document.querySelector('vaadin-combo-box');
> combobox.items = ['Bohrium', 'Boron', 'Bromine', 'Cadmium', 'Caesium', 'Calcium'];
> combobox.value = 'Bromine';
> ```

Comment: I know about the items property, I am passing it, but the value one is the one which I have tried and didn't worked :(

Comment: Another point, maybe you also knows the answer, I have another combobox (also vaadin' one), where my value comes from a computed binding, in this case how can I get the first value?  `<vaadin-combo-box label="Date" on-selected-item-changed="dateChanged" class="mini combobox" items="[[_getDates(dates)]]" item-label-path="name" value="[[_getFirstItem(_getDates(dates))]]"></vaadin-combo-box>` this doesn't work, neither use a var "items" inside the "getFirstItem"

Answer (score 1):

I simply set:

```
item-label-path="nombreCorto" item-value-path="idWaEmpresa" value="1"
```